# Running App in background even when the user terminated

Tags: swift, ios8, gps

I am seeking some help.

I would like to know if it is possible to keep my app running in background even when the user swiped the app from background.

I want my app to be running on the background to get the location using GPS.

Comment: Please don’t capitalize every word, it makes the question very difficult to read.

Comment: and what don't you post the code or what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2):

> even when the user terminated the app

Not if the user *terminated* the app. Terminated means *terminated*. It means exactly that the app is *not* running.

You can keep your app running in the background if the user *backgrounds* the app (as you say, you can do this if the app is using Core Location; similarly if the app is playing sound, etc.). But not if the user *terminates* it.